# Non selective query against large object type morethan 20,000 rows

Tags: trigger

I am facing the error in trigger code:

Code in that place:

public void duplicateBusiness() {

```
set<id> bId = new set<id>();
Map<id,string> duplicateCheck = new Map<id,string>();
Map<string,BusinessDetail__c> DupMap = new Map<string,BusinessDetail__c> ();

for (BusinessDetail__c b : newList)
{
    bId.add(b.id);
    duplicateCheck.put(b.id,b.DuplicateBusinessCheck__c);
}

List<BusinessDetail__c > StaActiList = new List<BusinessDetail__c >();
StaActiList  = [Select Name,DuplicateBusinessCheck__c, BusinessUnit__c,BusinessAlias__c from BusinessDetail__c where DuplicateBusinessCheck__c IN: duplicateCheck.values()];  


for(BusinessDetail__c b : StaActiList)
{
    DupMap.put(b.DuplicateBusinessCheck__c,b);    

}        if(!StaActiList.isEmpty())
{
    for (BusinessDetail__c b : newList)  
    {

        if(DupMap.containsKey(b.DuplicateBusinessCheck__c))
        {
            if(b.id != DupMap.get(b.DuplicateBusinessCheck__c).id)
            {
                b.addError('This account already has a business detail associated to it for this business. Duplicate business details are not allowed.');   

            }
        }
    }   
}
```

}

Error Query:

> StaActiList  = [Select Name,DuplicateBusinessCheck__c,
>   BusinessUnit__c,BusinessAlias__c from BusinessDetail__c where
>   DuplicateBusinessCheck__c IN: duplicateCheck.values()];

Error Message:

**Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter value includes null (fo**

could u please anyone help me how to rectify this error.

Comment: Please clarify - what type of field is DuplicateBusinessCheck__c ?

Comment: Formuka Field,return type as text field

Answer (score 1):

When querying against a large object type, your query must be selective - meaning it must be filtered using an indexed field. In your code, you're using a custom formula field which is not an indexed field by default.

You can open a case with Salesforce support and ask to index that specific field, provided it's a deterministic formula field.

> The following rules have to be true in order to index a Formula Field:
>
> - The formula contains fields from a single object only (not    relationship fields).
> - The formula field doesn't reference any non-deterministic functions    (e.g. SYSDATE).
> - The formula field doesn't reference any non-supported fields for    including in indexes.  This list isn't documented anywhere specifically (there are lots of special cases), but in Spring
>     12(176), createdById was non-supported, but in Summer 12 (178), it is 
>     supported.  Same story for CreatedDate.
> - The formula field doesn't contain references to Primary Keys (e.g Id)
> - The formula field does not use TEXT() function
> - If the formula references any Lookup fields, the field must not have    the option "What to do if the lookup record is deleted?" set
>     to    "Clear the value of this field."

If your formula field is non-deterministic per the criteria above, you'll have to get creative and find an indexed field to filter your query by.

Comment: How to index a formula field .could you give some snippet of code

Comment: There's no "snippet of code" to achieve this. Please bother reading my response.

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
for (BusinessDetail__c b : newList)
{
    bId.add(b.id);
    duplicateCheck.put(b.id,b.DuplicateBusinessCheck__c);
}
```

change to

```
for (BusinessDetail__c b : newList) 
{
    if (String.isNotBlank(b.DuplicateBusinessCheck__c)) {
        bId.add(b.id);
        duplicateCheck.put(b.id,b.DuplicateBusinessCheck__c);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Providing a solution is generally only the first part of a good answer. Giving an explanation for your approach (what does it do differently? why does it matter? what was the problem, and how does this avoid/work around/resolve it?) is just as important as the solution itself. You can [edit] your answer to include additional detail.